# Silverlight type of file

Tags: silverlight

I'm developing Silverlight application in expression blend2 and VS2008.
For that, I need to know which type of executable file it will be generated whether .exe or some other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight was meant to be run through a web browser.
When building SL applications, the result will be a .xap file.
The .xap file is really a zip file, and includes AppManifest.xaml, compiled output assembly of the Silverlight project (.dll) and any other resource files referred by the Silverlight application.